# How to using mixins for "mage/dataPost"?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, requirejs, mixins

I try to `mixin` a widget js file following guide at [here](https://alanstorm.com/modifying-a-jquery-widget-in-magento-2/).
I create a file `requirejs-config.js` in `view/frontend` directory.
There's `view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`:

```
var config = {
   config: {
      mixins: {
          'mage/dataPost': {
              'Vendor_Training/js/dataPost-mixin': true
          }
      }
   }
};
```

And there's `view/frontend/web/js/dataPost-mixin.js`:

```
define([
  'jquery'
], function($) {
    console.log('Mixin Working');
    return function (dataPost) {
       return dataPost;
    };
});
```

And it's exist on `pub/static/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/en_US/requirejs-config.js`. But it's not working.

And it's working when I use `map` on `requirejs-config.js` to override.

The mixins js file not calling when `dataPost.js` run.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you manage to do this?